# URL regex group catching

Tags: regex, url, regex-greedy

Hello I'm trying to find a regex that would catch the terms in a url.

For example, given:
https://stackoverflow.com, it would catch "stackoverflow"
and given https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask, it would catch "stackoverflow", "questions", "ask" and any potential terms in between the slash character after the domain name.

Up until now I managed to find the following regex but it cannot repeat catching groups

```
https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?([\da-z-]*)(?:[\.a-z]*)(?:\/([\da-z]*)\/?)+
```

Do you guys have any ways to resolve that issue?? that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I testet the answer of Michal M it appears not to get "www." so I updated it

```
/(?:\/(?:w{3}\.)?)\K([\w]+)/i
```

Edit: As soon as it's not important to match the "www." I placed it inside a non capturing group so it won't be captured. Btw I also placed the case insensitive modifier so "WWW." would be okay too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
(?:(\/))\K(\w+)
```

tested in notepad++

Comment: Also does not capture the 'questions', or 'ask' from  `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask`

Answer (score 0):

You may try using two separate regexes -- one for the hostname part and another for the terms in the path part. Then combine them with alternation construction and do global search:

```
https?:\/\/(?:\w+\.)*(\w+)\.\w+   # this would capture hostname "term"
  |
\/(\w+)                           # this would capture path "terms"
```

(Note: requires `/x` modifier.)

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nA8jT9/2

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I managed to rearrange it for it to work with the "www"

```
(?:\/(?:www\.)?)\K([\w\d]+)
```

Comment: `\w` includes `\d` so `\w` may be used instead of [\w\d]

Comment: What is the expected behaviour on the `https://meta.stackoverflow.com` input string?